# Notification after user becomes idle on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, python-idle

What's the best way of detecting when a user has been idle for X amount of time, and then detect when the user becomes immediately active?

I know there's NSWorkspace which provides will/did sleep/wake notifications, but I can't rely on that because the sleep setting is usually about ~15 minutes to never. I need to be able to detect if the user's been idle for ~1-2 minutes.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643579/objective-c-get-notifications-about-a-users-idle-state) provides a way to get the idle time. I'd like to avoid polling if possible.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid polling? You don't have to poll very frequently, probably. What resolution do you need? 1 minute? 1 second?Polling once per minute would not be inefficient. Even once per second wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Polling once per second leaks battery power on a laptop.  You really shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polling is your only option, to my knowledge.  As user1118321 points out, polling every O(minutes) is unlikely to cause any problems, performance or otherwise.

If your app has a GUI and receives UI events anyway, you could install a handler via `+[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:]` that resets your timer on each event.  That'll help reduce if not eliminate polls when the user is consistently active, in your own app at least.

Once you've determined that the user has been idle long enough, you could then install a global event tap to watch for the next event.  See for example `-[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:]`.

Note: you should use [`CGEventSourceSecondsSinceLastEventType`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12830508/790079) if at all possible rather than poking into the IO registry.  It's a formal, supported API and may be more efficient.  Not to mention it's way simpler.  There's also [UKIdleTimer](http://www.zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm) though it relies on Carbon, so may not be applicable.

Comment: I ended up using `CGEventSourceSecondsSinceLastEventType` to calculate when to fire NSTimer (60 seconds - idleTime). When the user is idle I enable my event tap with CGEventTapEnable. When the user is active again I disable it with the same command. The event tap is created at the start with `kCGEventMaskForAllEvents` and `kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly`. Seems to work great!